# How can I retrieve info from a specific json file

Tags: json, vba, excel

I have the following json file with multiple Descriptions and Customers (not mydata but this is the general structure).
I would like a fast way to find out which customers have a specific module.

For example, the customers which have the AD Module are Customer3,Customer4 (valid are only rows in CustomersDescs and not in 'ALL')

```
{
    "Descriptions": {
        "AA": "AA-Module1",
        "AD": "AD-Module2",
        "AL": "AL-Module3",
        "AAB": "AAB-Module4",
        "AAC": "AAC-Module5",
        "CE": "CE-Module6",
        "CL": "CL-Module7"
    },
    "WebServices": {
        "CA": "WS1",
        "CB": "WS2",
        "CL": "WS2",
        "DB": "WS3",
        "UA": "WS4"
    },
    "CustomersDescs": {
        "ALL": [
            "AA",
            "AD",
            "AL",
            "AAB",
            "AAC",
            "CE",
            "CL"
        ],
        "Customer1": [
            "AA",
            "AAC"
        ],
        "Customer2": [
            "AA",
            "CE"
        ],
        "Customer3": [
            "AA",
            "CE",
            "AD",
            "CL"
        ],
        "Customer4": [
            "AA",
            "CE",
            "AD",
            "CL"
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there any way to retrieve this info ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below example shows how to parse JSON and get the data which customers have a specific module. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.** Put the below code into VBA Project standard module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestModulesDistribution()

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON As Variant
    Dim sState As String
    Dim oModules As Object
    Dim sCustomer As Variant
    Dim sModule As Variant

    ' Read JSON content
    ' Put sourse JSON string to "\source.json" file in ASCII or Unicode charset
    sJSONString = ReadTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\source.json", -2)
    ' Process JSON
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    Set vJSON = vJSON("CustomersDescs")
    Set oModules = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    vJSON.Remove "ALL"
    For Each sCustomer In vJSON
        For Each sModule In vJSON(sCustomer)
            If Not oModules.Exists(sModule) Then Set oModules(sModule) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            oModules(sModule)(sCustomer) = ""
        Next
    Next
    ' Output result for example
    For Each sModule In oModules
        Debug.Print sModule
        Debug.Print vbTab & Join(oModules(sModule).Keys(), vbCrLf & vbTab)
    Next

End Sub

Function ReadTextFile(sPath As String, lFormat As Long) As String
    ' lFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, lFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```

Put your JSON to the file in ASCII or Unicode charset to the same folder as the workbook, and name it `source.json`, then run `TestModulesDistribution()`. After processing, the example output for me is as follows:

```
AA
    Customer1
    Customer2
    Customer3
    Customer4
AAC
    Customer1
CE
    Customer2
    Customer3
    Customer4
AD
    Customer3
    Customer4
CL
    Customer3
    Customer4
```

You can access to `oModules` dictionary items by module names, and get sub dictionaries, each of them contains customer names as keys for that particular module name.

BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).